# What's the advantage of putting nginx in front of uWSGI?

Tags: python, nginx, webserver, uwsgi

I see a lot of people running their python app, with nginx, which then communicates to nginx. uWSGI can run directly as a web server, and it looks quite fast and scalable, so what's the purpose of putting nginx in front of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[uWSGI documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/StaticFiles.html#serving-static-files-with-uwsgi-updated-to-1-9) answers this question:

> Generally your webserver of choice (Nginx, Mongrel2, etc. will serve
>   static files efficiently and quickly and will simply forward dynamic
>   requests to uWSGI backend nodes.
>
> The uWSGI project has ISPs and PaaS (that is, the hosting market) as
>   the main target, where generally you would want to avoid generating
>   disk I/O on a central server and have each user-dedicated area handle
>   (and account for) that itself. More importantly still, you want to
>   allow customers to customize the way they serve static assets without
>   bothering your system administrator(s).